# Ansible Playbook - fetch files from windows remote machine

Tags: powershell, ansible, fetch

I have a playbook that do 3 things -

1. find a list of directories in a host
2. find a list of files based to the directories it found
3. fetches the files to my local server.

I use the win_shell module for both finding the directories and the files, and the debugging results shows it finds them correctly.
But, when I use the fetch module, it states that the files I registered to the loop are directories -

```
---

- hosts: Host
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

  - name: Find DIR Directories
    win_shell: Get-ChildItem {{ partition }}:\Main\Production\App\    -Recurse -Directory "DIR" -Exclude "NotInUse" |% {Write-Host $_.FullName}
    register: dataDirs
  - debug:
      var: dataDirs

  - name: Find Each DIR Files
    win_shell: Get-ChildItem {{ item }} *.csv -Recurse |% {Write-Host $_.FullName}
    with_items: "{{ dataDirs.stdout_lines }}"
    register: dataFiles
  - debug:
     var: dataFiles

  - name: Fetch All Files
    fetch: src= "{{ item.stdout_lines }}" dest=/local/DIRFiles/
    with_items: "{{ dataFiles.results }}"
...
```

and the results are -

```
PLAY [Host] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Find DIR Directories] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [Host]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [Host] => {
    "dataDirs": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "Get-ChildItem d:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\ -Recurse -Directory \"DIR\" -Exclude \"NotInUse\" |% {Write-Host $_.FullName}",
        "delta": "0:00:00.643620",
        "end": "2020-10-07 09:39:50.528396",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2020-10-07 09:39:49.884775",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "d:\\DIR\\Production\\APP\\DIR\n",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "d:\\DIR\\Production\\APP\\DIR"
        ]
    }
}

TASK [Find Each DataForPnL Files] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [Host] => (item=d:\\DIR\\Production\\APP\\DIR)

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [Host] => {
    "dataFiles": {
        "changed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": true,
                "cmd": "Get-ChildItem d:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR *.csv -Recurse |% {Write-Host $_.FullName}",
                "delta": "0:00:00.555535",
                "end": "2020-10-07 09:39:53.259030",
                "failed": false,
                "item": "d:\\DIR\\Production\\APP\\DIR",
                "rc": 0,
                "start": "2020-10-07 09:39:52.703494",
                "stderr": "",
                "stderr_lines": [],
                "stdout": "d:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\PnlVol\\EURIBOR.csv\nD:d:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\SettleFix\\2019-10-08 SettleFix.csv\nd:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\SettleFix\\2019-10-28 SettleFix.csv\nd:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\SettleFix\\2019-12-24 SettleFix.csv\n",
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "d:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\PnlVol\\EURIBOR.csv",
                    "d:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\SettleFix\\2019-10-08 SettleFix.csv",
                    "d:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\SettleFix\\2019-10-28 SettleFix.csv",
                    "d:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\SettleFix\\2019-12-24 SettleFix.csv"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

TASK [Fetch All Files] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
failed: [Host] (item={'start': '2020-10-07 09:39:52.703494', 'stdout': 'd:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\PnlVol\\EURIBOR.csv\nD:d:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\SettleFix\\2019-10-08 SettleFix.csv\nd:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\SettleFix\\2019-10-28 SettleFix.csv\nd:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\SettleFix\\2019-12-24 SettleFix.csv\n', 'cmd': 'Get-ChildItem d:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR *.csv -Recurse |% {Write-Host $_.FullName}', 'stderr': '', 'changed': True, 'rc': 0, 'delta': '0:00:00.555535', 'end': '2020-10-07 09:39:53.259030', 'stdout_lines': ['d:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\PnlVol\\EURIBOR.csv\nD:d:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\SettleFix\\2019-10-08 SettleFix.csv\nd:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\SettleFix\\2019-10-28 SettleFix.csv\nd:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\SettleFix\\2019-12-24 SettleFix.csv\n'], 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False, 'item': 'd:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR', 'ansible_loop_var': 'item'}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "file": ".",
    "item": {
        "ansible_loop_var": "item",
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "Get-ChildItem d:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR *.csv -Recurse |% {Write-Host $_.FullName}",
        "delta": "0:00:00.555535",
        "end": "2020-10-07 09:39:53.259030",
        "failed": false,
        "item": "d:\\DIR\\Production\\APP\\DIR",
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2020-10-07 09:39:52.703494",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "d:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\PnlVol\\EURIBOR.csv\nD:d:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\SettleFix\\2019-10-08 SettleFix.csv\nd:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\SettleFix\\2019-10-28 SettleFix.csv\nd:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\SettleFix\\2019-12-24 SettleFix.csv\n",
        "stdout_lines": [
            d:\\DIR\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\PnlVol\\EURIBOR.csv",
                    "d:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\SettleFix\\2019-10-08 SettleFix.csv",
                    "d:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\SettleFix\\2019-10-28 SettleFix.csv",
                    "d:\\Main\\Production\\APP\\DIR\\SettleFix\\2019-12-24 SettleFix.csv"
        ]
    }
}

MSG:

**remote file is a directory, fetch cannot work on directories**

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Host                      : ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I tired to change the second win_shell to win_find, and it kept telling me the files are directories.

what am I doing wrong here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [fetch documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fetch_module.html) states that the [`src` parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fetch_module.html#parameter-src) is a value of type `string` representing the path to a single file. You are passing a `list`.

What you want to do is iterate over each file in `stdout_lines` in each `results`.

One way to achieve this:

```yaml
  - name: Fetch All Files
    fetch:
      src: "{{ item.1 }}"
      dest: /local/DIRFiles/
    with_subelements:
      - "{{ dataFiles.results }}"
      - stdout_lines
```

Ref:

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_lookup.html